# Big Cartel JS Format API returning dollars

Tags: bigcartel

I have a priject I'm working on and I need to format a number into a money value, I used the `Format.money()` function but the string it gave me had a dollar symbol, is there an option to change this to English Pounds (£)

Answer (score 0):

The API automatically uses the currency that's configured in the store admin - it can be changed from the Settings page. https://help.bigcartel.com/basics/settings/#basics

Comment: Could these be overridden if I'm developing a theme locally? As the basics settings are using British pounds

Comment: Ah, it looks like Dugway loads in the USD version of the API by default - you can specify the GBP version manually instead by using http://cache0.bigcartel.com/api/1/api.gbp.js - then when you load the theme into the store you can use the variable to bring it in.

Comment: Thanks for that, what variable are you referring to?

Comment: Instead of using `{{ 'api' | theme_js_url }}`.